# Formatting function to force digit lengths on each side of decimal point

Tags: r

I'm looking for an R function like `sprintf` that can easily format an output on both sides of the decimal point.  I know that `%04d` would work for integers, `%04d` formats decimal numbers before the decimal, and `%04f` formats decimal numbers after the decimal, but I can't seem to figure an elegant way to format on each side (I can, fortunately, think of a number of hideous ways).  Is there an easy way?  My desired output:

```
1 becomes 01.00
4.2 becomes 04.20
12.3 becomes 12.30
42.42 remains as is
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @nrussell R's `sprintf()` function is sufficient:

```
sprintf("%05.2f",x)
```

The sequence `05.2` in the format specifier indicates that the output of the number represented as a floating point (`f`) should be padded to the left with `0` so that the resulting string contains at least `5` characters, and that two digits should be displayed after the decimal point.

---

A more convoluted version would be to combine it with the `str_pad()` function from the `stringr` package. It has no advantage in this case compared to the solution using only `sprintf()`. I am adding it just for completeness, and because it was the solution I came up with.

```
x <- c(1, 4.2, 12.3, 42.42)
stringr::str_pad(sprintf("%.2f",x), 5, pad="0")
#[1] "01.00" "04.20" "12.30" "42.42"
```

The argument "5" passed to the `str_pad()` function indicates the length (width) of the string.

Comment: @nrussell Thank you. Bummer. I thought sprintf would be sufficient, at least that was my first version of the answer. Somehow I missed the option to include leading zeros. You should post this as an answer, I don't deserve the credits for this.

Comment: That's okay I don't feel like writing up an answer. The syntax for leading + trailing digits in `printf` is admittedly a little confusing; <padding character><total digits, including decimal point><.><number of digits to right of decimal point>.